# Nested Result set(Child and Parent) on same table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, multiple-resultsets

I'm using Entity framework to bring in the data to a mvc application.
The table contains 2 columns, One column contains the IDs(string) and other contains SQL Queries(string). I want to bring the data to a grid which will have 3 columns i.e. ID, Query and the result of that Query.My plan of approach was to bring the 2 columns in though a parent result set and get the result of the queries in a child result set and display them on the grid. How to I approach this?

Comment: How many records are you going to have in the table ?

Comment: the "child" queries don't have any repetitive structure (same column names)?

Comment: and the table and the query are versus the same oracle database?

Comment: The table has more that a few thousand records.
The sub query result will have at least 1 and less than 10 records.

Comment: Yes they are from same database but will be from different tables.|
The child queries will be mostly functions like max or count.